# Get User in Listerner With Symfony

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to get User (FOSuserBundle) in Listener With Symfony (2.7).

**My Listener service :**

```
    utilisateur_cabinet_listener:
    class: UtilisateurBundle\Listener\Cabinet
    arguments: [@router, @utilisateur_cabinet_repository]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

In Stackoverflow, you recommend to import container service, but the subjects date. Do you have another solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 access user and doctrine in a service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223988/symfony2-access-user-and-doctrine-in-a-service)

Comment: @SebTM is right, but note that `@security.context` is deprecated. Use `@security.token_storage` instead.

Comment: Did you found a way ? (Sf 3.0)